# Algoritmo de lista Java - Remover musica de playlist

Tags: java, lista, algoritmo

Preciso criar um algoritmo de lista em java que remova musicas de uma playlist, já tenho os botões de avançar, voltar, aleatório e play; preciso remover as musicas da playlist com um algoritmo de lista, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer

Comment: Já tentou fazer um [`list.remove(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Você já tem uma Lista?
2. Se 1 = sim, Qual o tipo da sua Lista?
3. Se 1 = sim, Que tipo de objetos sua Lista recebe?
4. Se 1 = não, poderia explicar melhor sua situação?

Se estiver utilizando *ArrayList* por exemplo, basta utilizar o método remove: 
`lista.remove(musica_que_deseja_remover);`